# sscanf cannot detect a number C

Tags: c, scanf

So I wrote this function in C using sscanf:

```
int parse_charstar(char *pointah)
{
    int numbeh;
    int retaahn = sscanf(pointah,"%*[^0123456789]%d",&numbeh);   

    printf("\n prent deeh numbeeh %d \n",numbeh);

    return numbeh;
}
```

I want to get a number out of a string if there, for eg.

```
"hello 121"
number: 121
```

Currently using the above I'm getting garbage values, can someone help?

EDIT:

So I found something interesting today. Apparently, this is what was happening!

My code was never wrong to begin with as pointed out by luoluo and dasblinkenlight.

Problem was *how* I was calling the program. I'm on linux.

I was calling it as:

```
parse_charstar("1000");
```

Output:

```
prent deeh numbeeh -1634553883
```

I tried:

```
parse_charstar(" 1000 "); // added spaces
```

Output?

```
prent deeh numbeeh 1000
```

Spot on.

Now can someone tell me why this happens?

**EDIT!!!**

Hell with it guys, use **strtol** , its made for this stuff.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/

Code copied shamelessly from the above page:

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* strtol */

int main ()
{
  char szNumbers[] = "2001 60c0c0 -1101110100110100100000 0x6fffff";
  char * pEnd;
  long int li1, li2, li3, li4;
  li1 = strtol (szNumbers,&pEnd,10);
  li2 = strtol (pEnd,&pEnd,16);
  li3 = strtol (pEnd,&pEnd,2);
  li4 = strtol (pEnd,NULL,0);
  printf ("The decimal equivalents are: %ld, %ld, %ld and %ld.\n", li1, li2, li3, li4);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Works as expected on my machine..

Comment: `%*[^0123456789]%d` may not do what you want. If I am not mistaken, you need to read a single digit.

Comment: @sjsam I think he wants to skip anything that *isn't* a digit, then read an integer... which is what that does.

Comment: This works like a charm: [demo](http://ideone.com/DYOkui). The format string can be simplified to `"%*[^0-9]%d"`

Comment: What's with the "namez" of the variables?

Comment: When `sscanf()` fails as expected, what is `retaahn`?

Comment: @chux see this! http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html#RETURN_VALUE

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, luoluo Check my edit, the function itself wasnt wrong but it was something else entirely

Answer (score 0):

A more restricted version of your `sscanf` would be

```
int retaahn = sscanf(pointah,"%*[^0-9]%d%*[^0-9]",&numbeh);
```

Note that this doesn't change anything in  your format string. I have just used `0-9` to mention the range and added a second `%*[^0-9]` to make things more explicit.

> Currently using the above I'm getting garbage values, can someone
>   help?

Probably because you're not passing the right arguments to the function. Just do a

```
printf("pointah : %s\n",pointah);
```

to see what is passed or set breakpoints and debug your program.

Comment: `0-9` vs. `0123456789` is tighter code but less portable.  Using `-` for a range is implementation defined behavior.  Rarely is this an problem though

Answer (score 0):

So since my code was never wrong, it turns out my problem was *how* I was calling this function.

This is how I solved it:

I was calling it as:

```
parse_charstar("1000");
```

I tried:

```
parse_charstar(" 1000 "); // added spaces
```

And it worked!

Check my edit above for more!!

Comment: The is why I was [asking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43749891/sscanf-cannot-detect-a-number-c?noredirect=1#comment74543998_43749891) what value was `retaahn` as that would bring to light the unexpected result.

Comment: Although I could not try that out, what would that have entailed? Would it have been something to do with errno?